# activate a class in java-script template rendered through backbone

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have this bootstrap-select's drop down filter in a javascript template, which is rendered through the backbone's view.

```
<script type="text/template" id="activities-template">
            <div class="span22">
                <div class="members">
                    <select class="selectpicker" multiple title='<i class="icon-filter"></i> Filter By'>
                        <% _.each(project_users, function(user){ %>
                            <option id=<%= user.id %>><%= user.first_name %></option>
                         <% }); %>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
</script>
```

when the ajax request is made it gets the projects_users and enable the selectpicker
At start all the drop-down options would be unselected.

```
@activities.fetch
     success: (activities) ->
        activities_html = that.template
          activities: _.groupBy activities.toJSON()
          has_more: that.activities.has_more
        that.$el.html activities_html

        $**('.selectpicker').selectpicker()**  //enable the selectpicker
```

when i click on a drop-down item, which is in checked state, makes ajax request to get the data... and again selectpicker is enabled ..thereby losing the previous state ( instead of showing the last selected option , its shows all drop-down option as unselected).

The problem seems that how to enable the select picker, only once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a class on your select picker, and only activate it if that class is not present:

```
@activities.fetch
  success: (activities) ->
    activities_html = that.template
      activities: _.groupBy activities.toJSON()
      has_more: that.activities.has_more
    that.$el.html activities_html

    select_picker = $('.selectpicker')
    unless select_picker.hasClass 'active'
      select_picker.addClass('active').selectpicker()
```

Be aware that this will work as long as you don't re-render your Backbone view. If you do, you'll be losing the 'active' class. It's possible that this is the real reason your `<select>` is being reset; if this is the case, then you should keep track of the current selection in your view, and update your template to use that when it renders. For instance, you might pass in an 'active_id' variable to the template; if it's present, then set that option to be shown, and add the 'active' class to the `<select>`.